# echo link and string

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a string inside a link, however it doesn't appear on the page. 
Here's my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['search']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
echo '<a href="user.php?username=' . $row['username'] . '>$row['username']</a>';
}

?>
```

*The code previously worked when it just echoed `echo $row['username'];`*

Comment: `echo '<a href="user.php?username=' . $row['username'] . '">' . $row['username'] . '</a>';` - Notice that you forgot the ending `"` character of the `href` attribute and that you can only use variable expansion inside double quoted strings.

Comment: Glad that I could help, you should read up on how [string parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) works

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing properly the `echo string`. This works:

```
echo "<a href=\"user.php?username={$row['username']}\">{$row['username']}</a>";
```